# List is empty when loading page

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Im trying to load data into a list using a store. When i run my code the list value is blank, the list is not empty but it is blank.

Here is the part of my controller where i try to add data to store.

```
  var loginStore = Ext.getStore('instance');
               var record = [{id:id, issued_at:issued, instance_url:instance, signature:sig, access_token:access, myBaseUri:baseUri}];
               loginStore.add(record);
```

Here is the part of the view where i make the list

```
{
               xtype :'list',
               id : 'list1',
               loadingText: 'Loading Projects',
               emptyText: '<div>No Projects Found</div>',
               onItemDisclosure: true,
               itemTpl: '<div>{issued_at}</div>',
               height: 320,
               store : 'instance'
```

}

This doesnt work but when i replace `itemTpl:'<div>{issued_at}</div>'` with

```
itemTpl:'<div>{id}</div>'
```

it seems to work. What am I  doing wrong?

Here is my store:

```
Ext.define('GS.store.instance',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['GS.model.login'],
config:{
    model: 'GS.model.login'

}
});
```

And here is my model:

```
Ext.define('GS.model.login',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields:[
            {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'issued_at', type:'string'},
            {name: 'instance_url', type:'string'},
            {name: 'signature', type:'string'},
            {name: 'access_token', type:'string'},
            {name: 'myBaseUri', type:'string'}
      ]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i was missing the config option on my model definition.

```
Ext.define('GS.model.login',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config:{
    fields:[ 'id','issued_at','instance_url','signature','access_token','myBaseUri' ]
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you create your record is wrong. Try this way :

```
var record = Ext.create('YOUR_MODEL', {
    id : id,
    issued_at: issued,
    instance_url: instance,
    ...
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: after using your suggestion im still getting the same results

Comment: Could you add the store definition as well the model in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using this example:

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   model: 'Contact',
},

   data: [
       { firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'  },
       { firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'  },
       { firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer' },
       { firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'   },
       { firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'  },
       { firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'  },
       { firstName: 'Jacky',   lastName: 'Nguyen'  },
       { firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'   },
       { firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'},
       { firstName: 'Nigel',   lastName: 'White'   },
       { firstName: 'Don',     lastName: 'Griffin' },
       { firstName: 'Nico',    lastName: 'Ferrero' },
       { firstName: 'Jason',   lastName: 'Johnston'}
   ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.List', {
   fullscreen: true,
   itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div>',
   store: store,
});
```

Comment: When you add code to your answer. First paste your code, select it and then tap the code button to format it.

Answer (score 0):

As you get values in the list when using id instead of issued_at, the problem seems to be, not with the functions/models/store so much, but with the issued_at variable itself. Are you certain it's getting through to the store?

Try adding this when your store has loaded, or run it in the browser using for instance chrome

```
console.log(Ext.getStore("instance").getAt(0).data.id);
console.log(Ext.getStore("instance").getAt(0).data.issued_at);
```

You should see some result from your first data item.

If you get an id but just "undefined" for issued_at, you'll know that the issue is with the records. And in that case I would try to log your `issued` variable before you try to add it to the store to make sure that it is actually defined.

Please report with results for further help/discussions if needed.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but its still showing blank on the message box. I even hardcoded some dummy values `var record = Ext.create('GS.model.login',{                                        id:'dummy ',isued_at:'dummy value '... })`

Comment: I figured out the problem. something was wrong with the model definition. instead of `{name:'id,type:'string'}....` i used `['id','issued_ad',...]`. Its working fine now